# Using if and elif within a for loop in Python to switch characters in string

Tags: python

this is a very basic problem that, given my familiarity with Python, I should be able to solve, and am perhaps missing something very obvious. It concerns my understanding if Python's if and elif functions.

Below, I have defined two functions. The goal of both is, for a string made up of a's and b's, to switch the a's to b's and the b's to a's. switch2 works but switch1 doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.

My understanding is that, when an 'if' statement is False, Python simply continues to the next line rather than exiting the for loop completely. In this case, switch1 should also work, but it doesn't. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
def switch1(s):
    s = list(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'a':
            s[i] = 'b'
        if s[i] == 'b':
            s[i] = 'a'
    return s

def switch2(s):
    s = list(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'a':
            s[i] = 'b'
        elif s[i] == 'b':
            s[i] = 'a'
    return s

switch1('abab')
switch2('abab')
```

Expected results for both are 'baba', which switch2('abab') returns, but not switch1('abab'). Why is this? The only difference is that I change the last if to elif in switch2.

Comment: In case 1, you switch `s[i]` to `'b'`. Then you check whether `s[i]` equals `'b'`… In the second case that second check isn't performed if the first one was true, since the statements are linked by an `else` clause.

Comment: this is a very basics of conditionals

Comment: OK. I believe the solution is that the a's were double-flipped for the switch1 function, which is why switch1('abab') returns 'aaaa' rather than 'baba'. But this would mean that the second check would still always be performed? Why would it not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif` is only evaluated if the preceding `if` fails. whereas, all `ifs` are evaluated.

In switch1, First `if` is changing 'a' to 'b' and second `if` is changing back that 'b' to 'a'. Thus, the output is unchanged

switch2 works as expected since `elif` is not evaluated when `if` is `true`

Comment: final output for switch1 will be `aaaa`

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in a comment to my original post, but thank you. I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: yes @Shijith . all `a`s remain unchanged.